# Docker-ce on RHEL/CentOS 8 - No outbound network access for docker containers

Tags: docker, rhel, centos8

I've installed docker-ce on RHEL 8 and everything seems to work fine, except that docker containers do not have any network access. I have firewalld service disabled and selinux in permissive mode. Example, I create a container running Alpine with the following command:

`docker run -it alpine /bin/sh`

Inside the container `ifconfig` returns:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02
      inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:2101 (2.0 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

But I not able to execute ping, apk or anything that replies on egress. I can establish ingress access by specifying which port to bind with host. For example this works:

`docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 nginx`

But no egress works in that example either. Using docker in RHEL 7, ingress and egress works fine. How do I enable egress network on RHEL 8 with docker-ce.

With firewalld enabled, I noticed this message in `systemctl stats firewalld`

```
WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-ab206699df7f -o br-ab206699df7f -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
```

Although as mentioned, even with firewalld service disabled, egress does not work.

Comment: After disabling firewalld, have you restarted the Docker daemon?

Comment: You know, when you spend so much time on something you get tunnel vision. @larsks that was exactly my problem! I was stopping firewalld but did not think to restart docker daemon after killing the firewall. Restarting docker daemon after stoping firewall fixed my issue. Please feel free to leave an answer and I will mark as correct. Thanks, you rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @larsks, the problem was that I needed to restart docker-ce service after stoping firewall.

`systemctl restart docker`

Comment: I was facing same issue. I tried the solution by stopping firewall first and then restarted my daemon and restarted container. but still not able to fix issue. If set Apache reverse proxy, will it work?